# https even just for testing purposes?

Tags: facebook, flash, testing, https

I know that you need a secure https thingy to hose a valid app on. But if I just want to test some stuff, like how to make use of the social plugins from within a flash app and so on, do I need a secured url as well?
Or is there something like a testuser for that too, that doesn't care about this but let's me simply test the stuff?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"All Canvas apps must process signed_request (fb_sig will be removed) and obtain an SSL certificate (unless you are in Sandbox mode)." Via: Facebook Dev Blog - https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497

Just set your app to sandbox mode. And you should be all set. Otherwise you could always look into a service such as this: http://www.social-server.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess my application is still in sandbox mode, yet I can't call up the canvas url, to test what it works like in facebook, without getting an error regarding the app beeing currently not hosted on a ssl-server. I will try the social-server. :)

Comment: The application needs to be in sandbox mode, and the user accessing it has to have Secure Browsing disabled in their Facebook profile:

The little down arrow it the top right -> Account Settings -> Security -> Secure Browsing

Comment: @topher-j And even this is being phased out at the moment, so hurray for self signed certificates :P

Answer (score 2):

This is no longer possible. Facebook now requires a HTTPS connection: the Secure Browsing option under Account Settings is no longer available.